# Calling Function Inside the Function itself

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why did we call the function inside the function rather than calling it outside?

```css
let i = 0;
let images = [];
const time = 500;

images[0] = 'Images/carousel1.jpg';
images[1] = 'Images/carousel2.jpg';
images[2] = 'Images/carousel3.jpg';

const changeImg = () => {

    document.slide.src = images[i];

    if(i < images.length - 1) {
        i++;
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    
    setTimeout('changeImg()', time);

};

onload = changeImg;
```

```html
<img src="" name="slide">
```

Comment: Outside it's assigned to an `onload` event, so it does get called outside the function. Inside, it's intended to repeat itself after a delay of `time`.

Comment: I'd prefer to write the inner call like this: `setTimeout(changeImg, time);`. I don't think too many people pass a string to evaluate anymore.

Comment: Updating `i` can be done more succinctly too. `i = ++i % images.length`. This will roll it back to `0` once the `++i` increments to a value that equals `images.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, your question, is why do we call `setTimeout('changeImg()', time);` from inside the `changeImg` function, well let's take a look.

When the onload event triggers, `changeImg` will be called, kicking things off. Which will swap out images, based on the value of `i`. Each time  `changeImg` is called  it schedules the next call of `changeImg` for `time` seconds in the future.

This has a couple features to how it's currently implemented which may be interesting...

First we could have used `setInterval` to call the `changeImg` function, from outside of the function, but depending on the timings involved could lead to off time swapping of the images.

As these setInterval/setTimeout functions do not guarantee when they will fire, just that they will sometime after their set timeouts, so it's possible one or more such calls could trigger next to each other,  messing with the timings...

By using the nested setTimeout, you guarantee only one such event is pending at any given time, and only after the work has been done, the next event gets scheduled.

So we can see that by nesting the call, we get a guaranteed order and min span of time between calls/images swaps.

You can play with this [playground](https://jsbin.com/ciyaripoje/1/edit?js,output), to see how the timings can get out of sync... just play with the slider control a bit and you will see the slides go out of sync.